# My ChartJS dates don't show up correctly from coinranking API

Tags: reactjs, api, chart.js, cryptocurrency

Below is my code to display a chart of a crypto coin and it's change in prices over a period of time. I have also included the jsx file and the .env file

jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Col, Row, Typography } from 'antd';

const { Title } = Typography;

const LineChart = ({ coinHistory, currentPrice, coinName }) => {
  const coinPrice = [];
  const coinTimestamp = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < coinHistory?.data?.history?.length; i += 1) {
    coinPrice.push(coinHistory?.data?.history[i].price);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < coinHistory?.data?.history?.length; i += 1) {
    coinTimestamp.push(new Date(coinHistory?.data?.history[i].timestamp).toLocaleDateString());
  }
  const data = {
    labels: coinTimestamp,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Price In USD',
        data: coinPrice,
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: '#0071bd',
        borderColor: '#0071bd',
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Row className="chart-header">
        <Title level={2} className="chart-title">{coinName} Price Chart </Title>
        <Col className="price-container">
          <Title level={5} className="price-change">Change: {coinHistory?.data?.change}%</Title>
          <Title level={5} className="current-price">Current {coinName} Price: $ {currentPrice}</Title>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Line data={data} options={options} />
    </>
  );
};

export default LineChart;
```

.js file:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
  'x-rapidapi-host': process.env.REACT_APP_CRYPTO_RAPIDAPI_HOST,
  'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPIDAPI_KEY,
};
const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoApiHeaders });

export const cryptoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'cryptoApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_CRYPTO_API_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCryptos: builder.query({
      query: (count) => createRequest(`/coins?limit=${count}`),
    }),

    getCryptoDetails: builder.query({
      query: (coinId) => createRequest(`/coin/${coinId}`),
    }),

    getCryptoHistory: builder.query({
      query: ({ coinId, timeperiod }) => createRequest(`coin/${coinId}/history?timeperiod=${timeperiod}`),
    }),

    getExchanges: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest('/exchanges'),
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetCryptosQuery,
  useGetCryptoDetailsQuery,
  useGetExchangesQuery,
  useGetCryptoHistoryQuery,
} = cryptoApi;
```

.env:

```
REACT_APP_RAPIDAPI_KEY =  'my_key'
REACT_APP_CRYPTO_API_URL = 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com'
REACT_APP_NEWS_API_URL = 'https://bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com'
REACT_APP_NEWS_RAPIDAPI_HOST = 'bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com'
REACT_APP_CRYPTO_RAPIDAPI_HOST ='coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com'

ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
```

When I run the React code all I get are 19/1/1970 as dates on the chart, I am not sure why the real dates are not showing up in the charts. Other data is showing up so I believe the key is fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue ... looks like the timestamps show up no matter what timePeriod is passed to the api ... same for '7d', '1m', '1y', '5y' etc. Can anyone help us?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ChartJS V.3 ->

First your should add a date adapter, if you use date-fns or moment there is an adapter for each one example :

```
import {
        Chart as ChartJS,
        LinearScale,
        PointElement,
        LineElement,
        Tooltip,
        Filler,
        TimeScale,
    } from 'chart.js'
    
    import "chartjs-adapter-moment"
    
    ChartJS.register(
        LinearScale,
        TimeScale,
        PointElement,
        Filler,
LineElement,
    Tooltip,
)
```

Then you have to add the Time format in your xAxes Options :

```
  x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: "day",
                        displayFormats: {
                            day: "MMM DD YYYY" // or whatever you want to display your date
                        }
                    },
}
```

If you use ChartJS V2:

Don't install the adapter, it's not necessary but add in your Scales Options :

```
xAxes: [
                    {
                        // stacked: true,
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'day',
                            displayFormats: {
                                day: 'MMM DD YYYY'
                            }
                        },
                    },
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a minor change while pushing dates into timeStamp array.
Do this

```
coinTimeStamp.push(new Date(coinHistory.data.history[i].timestamp*1000).toLocaleDateString());
```

You need to multiply the timestamp by 1000.